# TextView overflowing in RecyclerView width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im following a tutorial to display a list of items with recyclerview.

It has an ImageView on the left, and TextViews of the right.

However, if the text is long, overflows to the right. How would I make it so that it does not overflow, and make a new line instead? Specially if the text may or may not be long, depending on user input

[image]

In my_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/myText1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myText1"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:layout_width = "0dp"` and add end constraint to end(parent) of `myText2`
Also You do not need two `ContraintLayout` one layout is enough

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myText2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/myText1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myText1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the end or right constraint to parent in your TextView, then set the layout_width to 0dp(match_constraint)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `myText2` with

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/myText1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myText1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi replace your code with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
             
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/myText1"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
            
                    
                    />

               



            </RelativeLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```